# Authentication of temporary worker without a badge (physical security)

Tags: authentication, physical

In our company we have a procedure to verify internal worker but we cannot use it for temporary worker. We cannot use badges and because of privacy reasons we cannot use any photos. Is there any other way to authenticate them? For example I meet someone very late in the company building and nobody else is there. How can I find out whether the person belongs to the company or not?

Comment: This question is really lacking background information. What is your procedure and why can't you use it for temporary workers? And why can't you use badges? And how high is your security standard anyway?

Comment: Also, do your permanent employees have badges? It's not clear if you can;y use badges for temps or for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago we used "generic" badges with the word *Contractor* and a number.  There was an intranet page with the names of current contractors and their badge numbers.  Contractors were required to wear their badges and told they must produce picture ID (like a driver's license) on request of anyone wearing an employee badge.

This was in a medium-security environment with few contractors or temporary workers, and it worked pretty well.